# Java pseudo timer

Tags: java, eclipse, date, timer

I am currently working on a project in java. It is a basic RTS simulator. The issue I,m currently having is the one to do with timers.

For example:

I start a 0:00 seconds.

A barrack takes 25 seconds to build.

I need to store the starting time and the ending time of the operation. So it stores something like and Event "BARRACK 0:00 0:25".

I have no problems doing it in real time - but its not what I want.

I want it to automatically create a start timestamp and end timestamp on a pseudo real time scale (so I get all the logs of any time length right at execution). Normal data types I am aware of at do not help.

Anyone has any suggestions on what I could use to create this type of pseudo timeline?

Comment: Why don't you use a Swing Timer? Or just record the time that the event should happen, and check against that time in your game loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

Are you saying you want a fake clock that keeps time but at a faster rate than your computer's real clock?

Java has two good date-time frameworks:

- Joda-Time (3rd party library, popular)
- java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310)

Both frameworks have a pluggable "clock" class. You can replace the default implementation which uses the computer's physical clock chip. Your replacement can move time along at a different clip.

Answer (score 0):

I would start a new thread for each operation.

and take the current time stamp in a date form or calendar form

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

** or **

long millis = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

the barrak class has to have its own long variables for the startBuilding and endBulding time.

and this way, every instance of barrack will have the right time stamp.

Hope I understood you correctly , and this helps.

have a great day.